# ODI studio on Windows server

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

How to setup ODI studio on a Windows server 2012 R2  so that logged in OS users can use ODI Studio 12.2 ?

Do each user have to have their own install of ODI Studio 12.2 in their private directory ?

What privileges are needed for a  OS level user on Windows 2012 R2 server to install their own copy of ODI studio 12.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I usually install it in a root-level directory such as `c:\app\oracle\odi` and grant the developers read and execute privileges on it.

The user settings are store separately in each user's profile directory `%APPDATA%\odi`.

Comment: The path in my case is C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\odi\studio\odi.exe . To test the perms I create a local test user, granted read and exec on the above path  and added the user to Remote Desktop User role so that the test user can login remotely.  When I login as test user and start the odi.exe ( tried from command line as well) I do not see the studio starting.

Comment: IIRC the first time you start ODI it should ask you the JDK path. Is JDK installed? Does `java -version` return anything if you run it as your test user?

Comment: Yes jdk is installed. I logged in as test user and was able to run following commands - 
where java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe

java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
whoami 
ravi_test

Comment: Anything else i should try ?